# Invalid object name 'RefreshToken

Tags: asp.net-core

i am trying to make a login system with jwt and refresh token using sql as db and asp.net core as frontend.

and i get below error. in data base i have made user table but not RefreshToken table as RefreshToken is going to generated and saved on cookie of the browser.

**Invalid object name 'RefreshToken**

**here is my Model User**

```
  public class User
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            public string Username { get; set; }
    
            [JsonIgnore]
            public string Password { get; set; }
    
            [JsonIgnore]
            public List<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
        }
```

**here is another model RefreshToken**

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
    
    namespace Api_R.Entities
    {
      [Owned]
        public class RefreshToken
        {
            [Key]
            [JsonIgnore]
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Token { get; set; }
            public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
           /////////
        }
    }
```

**and here i am using my controller**

```
          public AuthenticateResponse Authenticate(AuthenticateRequest model, string ipAddress)
            {
                var user = _apiDbContext.User.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == model.Username && x.Password==model.Password);
    
                // validate
                if (user == null)//|| !BCryptNet.Verify(model.Password, user.PasswordHash))
                    throw new AppException("Username or password is incorrect");
    
                // authentication successful so generate jwt and refresh tokens
                var jwtToken = _jwtUtils.GenerateJwtToken(user);
                var refreshToken = _jwtUtils.GenerateRefreshToken(ipAddress);
               
                user.RefreshTokens.Add(refreshToken);
    
                // remove old refresh tokens from user
                removeOldRefreshTokens(user);
    
               
    
                return new AuthenticateResponse(user, jwtToken, refreshToken.Token);
            }
```

and now i am getting error invalid object name refresh token

Comment: You can see this [article](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2020/05/25/aspnet-core-3-api-jwt-authentication-with-refresh-tokens) may helpful.

Comment: i have seen the article working well as explained but when i use to do same thing using sql db it thows error as mentioned .